# Java Packages Concepts

Tags: java

> Person.java

```
package A;
public class Person {
    public String name , surname;

    public Person() {
        name = " Unknown ";
        surname = " Unknown ";
    } 

    public Person(String n , String s) {
        name = n;
        surname = s;
    }

    public Person(Person p1) {
        name = p1.name;
        surname = p1.surname;
    }
}
```

> ContactInfo.java

```
 package A.B;
    import A.Person;

    public class ContactInfo extends Person {

        public String phone;

        public ContactInfo() {
             phone = "Unvalid ";
        } 

        public ContactInfo(String n , String s , String phn) {
            super(n,s);
            phone = phn;
        } 

        public ContactInfo(ContactInfo ci) {
            super(ci);
            phone = ci.phone;
        }
    }
```

Employee.java

```
package A.B.C;
import A.B.ContactInfo;
public class Employee extends ContactInfo {

    int salary;

    public Employee() {
        salary = 0;
    }

    public Employee(String n , String s , String phn ,int sal) {
        super(n,s,phn);
        salary = sal;
    } 

    public Employee(Employee e) {
        super(e);
        salary = e.salary;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Name: "+name+surname+ " Phone: "+phone+ " Salary: "+salary);
    } 
}
```

> Office.java

```
//import A.B.C.Employee;
  import A.B.C.*;

class Office {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

       Employee e1 = new Employee();
       System.out.println();
       e1.show();

       Employee e2 = new Employee(" John "," Snow "," 001122 ",123);
       System.out.println();
       e2.show();

       Employee e3 = new Employee(e2);
       System.out.println();
       e3.show();          
    }
}
```

> As in Office.java file when i using this statment :  **import A.B.C.Employee;**
>
> it will shows the desired output but when i using :  **import
>   A.B.C.*;** it will shows errors. Why it is always fails to get the correct path?
>
> Little help is needed to understand it .

Comment: `it will shows errors` - What errors? I'm not going to pretend I understand the question, but replacing import `a.b.c.Employee` with `import a.b.c.*`(please use lower-case for package names) should work unless you have some collision in imports(like a.b.Employee and a.b.c.Employee)

Comment: What errors is is giving?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj Error is : Cannot access Employee